# ComboBox Does Not Update After Switching To Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

so I am still quite a noob at VBA and I made two ComboBoxes, first ComboBox is for the list of the sheets in the workbook and the second ComboBox is the list of names that reads in from a specific column. It works fine for first time trying, however, when switching to another sheet through using the first combobox, the second ComboBox still has the old list of names from the previous sheet that I opened. I have been looking for solutions for hours on how to get the second ComboBox to update once a new sheet has been selected from the first ComboBox and I was wondering if there is any way I could get the second ComboBox to refresh? Here is my code that deals with two text boxes:

This is the function when the UserForm gets started, I first populate the first ComboBox with the sheets in the workbook then I populate the second ComboBox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Worksheet object
Dim sht As Worksheet

'Sets the ComboBox1 to "Select a Project"
ComboBox1.Value = "Select a Project"

'Name of the Sheet That is Excluded
Dim prjSum As String
prjSum = "Pjct Resource Summary"


'For every sheet in the workbook
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not (sht.name = prjSum) Then 'Excluding PRS
        ComboBox1.AddItem (sht.name) 'Add to the ComboBox1 list
    End If
Next sht

'Populate ComboBox2 starting from E4 to the last name in E column
ComboBox2.List = ActiveSheet.Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)).Value
End Sub
```

Here I just set textboxes from their respective cells. I tried doing populating my second ComboBox here but then for some reason, my ComboBox would show nothing or show a name from the first sheet in the workbook.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

currWrkSheet = ComboBox1.Value


If currWrkSheet = "Select a Project" Then
    MsgBox ("Select a Project")
    Exit Sub
End If



'ComboBox2.List = ActiveSheet.Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)).Value

'Once getting the value of the combobox, it should show the values from the corresponding texboxes/comboboxes
TextBox2.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 2).Value 'BU
TextBox3.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 3).Value 'Function
TextBox4.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 4).Value 'Resource Type
TextBox5.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 6).Value 'Project Role
TextBox6.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 7).Value 'Project Responsibility

'TextBoxes for the Months
TextBox7.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 8).Value
TextBox8.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 9).Value
TextBox9.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 10).Value
TextBox10.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 11).Value
TextBox11.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 12).Value
TextBox12.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 13).Value
TextBox13.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 14).Value
TextBox14.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 15).Value
TextBox15.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 16).Value
TextBox16.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 17).Value
TextBox17.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 18).Value
TextBox18.Value = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 19).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you never update the List of ComboBox2. It is always populated with the contents of the activesheet at the time of of the initialization of the form. If you want the list to change according to the selection in combobox1, you need to use the change event of combobox1 to reset the combobox2 list.

Comment: @VincentG Ah okay, figured it out. Thank you so much!